# Is a CPU usage of 80-100 % bad?

Tags: java, android, performance, hardware

I'm running `Services` and their `Threads` in the background every 2-3 seconds.

Hardware monitoring of Android Studio shows:

```
Memory: 0,7-9 MB (Free), 12-21 MB (Allocated)
CPU: 80-100 % (User), 0-2% (Kernel)
```

The **app is stable** (no crash after the continuous running of 1 hour), **but reacts with a delay** of less than a second. I think the small delay occurs because the Services are firing many threads, so the cores are busy and need to free a slot for the UI thread first.

I would like you to correct me if I misinterpret the information.

Is the average high CPU usage bad for the device or app stability?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: need `Service` code plz

Comment: Mostly bad for the battery, it will be drained in a few hours.